# Reading formatted data from a text file

Tags: vba, file, text, input

The following code reads in values (in a loop) from a text file containing two numbers per line into X and Y. The first iteration of the loop gives correct values for X and Y (70, 210). The next iteration onwards, the X and Y values are not what is contained in the file (210, 210 for the second iteration instead of 0, 210). I ust be making a mistake but I can't seem to find it !

```
Sub main()
Dim X As Double
Dim Y As Double

Open "perforatedcircles.txt" For Input As #1

Do While Not EOF(1)
Input #1, X, Y
Loop
Close #1

End Sub
```

Sample Contents of "perforatedcircles.txt":

```
70.000 210.000
0.000 210.000
-70.000 -210.000
```

Answer (score 0):

How was the input file created?  It appears to be in a different format than the Input # directive is expecting.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243386(v=vs.60).aspx

"Data read with Input # is usually written to a file with Write #. Use this statement only with files opened in Input or Binary mode."

"Note   To be able to correctly read data from a file into variables using Input #, use the Write # statement instead of the Print # statement to write the data to the files. Using Write # ensures each separate data field is properly delimited."

Given the space delimitation, you'll need to parse the file differently.  Here is one example:

```
Dim iLine As Integer, 
Dim sFile As String
Dim sData As String
Dim sLine() As String
Dim sSplitLine() As String
Dim x as Double
Dim y as Double

'read the whole file into 1 string variable
sFile = "perforatedcircles.txt"
Open sFile For Input As #1
sData = Input(LOF(1), 1)
Close #1
sLine = Split(sData, vbCrLf)
For iLine = 0 To UBound(sLine)
    sSplitLine = Split(sLine(UBound(sLine)), " ")

    x = CDbl(sSplitLine(0))
    y = CDbl(sSplitLine(1))
    'Do Stuff with your numbers here
Next iLine
```

Comment: The file was written in Matlab with space as the delimiter.